# Centrar span con before en vertical al botón

Tags: css

Estoy teniendo un problema, estoy tratando de centrar mi element `spinner` de manera vertical utilizando `:before`

¿Alguien sabe que puede ser?

```css
@keyframes spinner {
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
.spinner {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;

}
.spinner:before {
  content: '';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  animation: spinner .6s linear infinite;
  top: 50%;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 30px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<button>
 <span class="spinner"></span>
 <span>
    Esto es un boton
 </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que necesitas agregar la propiedad:

- `vertical-align: middle;` en la clase `.spinner`

Y modificar esta:

- `top: 15%;` en `.spinner:before`

```css
@keyframes spinner {
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
.spinner {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.spinner:before {
  content: '';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  top: 15%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  animation: spinner .6s linear infinite;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 30px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<button>
 <span class="spinner"></span>
 <span>
    Esto es un boton
 </span>
</button>
```

Probando con diferente altura en el botón...

```css
@keyframes spinner {
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
.spinner {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.spinner:before {
  content: '';
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  top: 15%;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  animation: spinner .6s linear infinite;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  height: 300px;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<button>
 <span class="spinner"></span>
 <span>
    Esto es un boton
 </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Funciona, excelente solo una duda, porque debe ir al `15%` en el top y no al `50%`?

Comment: Desconociendo el fundamento teórico y sin posibilidad de ofrecerte una referencia bibliográfica, asumo que el porcentaje no toma el centro del spinner como coordenada sino sus tangentes para ubicarlo en su contenedor padre... Te propongo el siguiente ejercicio: Duplica la propiedad `height` del botón, también duplica la propiedad `height` y `width` de `.spinner `. Finalmente, modifica al 50% `top` y `left` en `.spinner:before`. Te darás cuenta que el spinner se ubica justo en el cuarto cuadrante cartesiano. _Debajo de el eje positivo de x y a la derecha del eje negativo de y_